How to get cleaned data from a noisy tsv file using regex?
I've to clean the data which is stored in a tsv to a dataframe using regex , for reference the data looks like this
ps8trw17rlo16s  dh7r1wjixjse72  Theoretical movements expensive. In rural areas, especially at The Fox  positive    2020-06-01 00:00:00
psw4o545h8gc2h  dhykkf6486p9ra  Ave SW components on the East in 1498, and soon
 Educational campaigns encounter difficulty. To Socrates, a person will experience a continental    positive    2020-06-01 00:07:00
pscnx5eqtjocca  dhn4dhhp3wm5lt  Kinds are larger, possibly over two million. The country is the city's average. Hollywood    Fril Functional four national
 Pp. Cayton, Cage is     Has opened (RTA) coordinates the operation positive    2020-06-01 00:14:00

the data is malformed in nature and I've to segregate the data into pid, uid , text , prediction , datetile
This is my code
# Sample file path
input_file_path = 'logs.tsv'
output_file_path = 'cleaned_logs.txt'

# Read the malformed TSV file and write it to a text file
with open(input_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile, open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)
import pandas as pd
import re

# Define regex patterns for each column
patterns = {
    'pid': r'[A-Za-z0-9]+',  # Matches a word (alphanumeric characters)
    'uid': r'[A-Za-z0-9]+',  # Matches a word (alphanumeric characters)
    'text': r'([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)',  # Matches the entire text (paragraph)
    'prediction': r'(positive|negative)',  # Matches 'positive' or 'negative'
    'datetime': r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?'  # Matches datetime format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
}

# Function to clean each row based on its pattern
def clean_row(row):
    columns = row.split('\t')
    if len(columns) != 5:
        return [None, None, None, None, None]  # Return a list of Nones if the row is malformed
    
    cleaned_data = []
    cleaned_data.append(re.match(patterns['pid'], columns[0]).group(0) if re.match(patterns['pid'], columns[0]) else None)
    cleaned_data.append(re.match(patterns['uid'], columns[1]).group(0) if re.match(patterns['uid'], columns[1]) else None)
    cleaned_data.append(re.match(patterns['text'], columns[2]).group(0) if re.match(patterns['text'], columns[2]) else None)
    cleaned_data.append(re.match(patterns['prediction'], columns[3]).group(0) if re.match(patterns['prediction'], columns[3]) else None)
    cleaned_data.append(re.match(patterns['datetime'], columns[4]).group(0) if re.match(patterns['datetime'], columns[4]) else None)
    return cleaned_data

# Read the cleaned text file
with open(output_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    rows = file.readlines()

# Initialize a list to collect cleaned rows
cleaned_rows = []

# Process each row with its corresponding pattern
for row in rows:
    row = row.strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
    cleaned_row = clean_row(row)
    cleaned_rows.append(cleaned_row)

# Convert the cleaned rows to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned_rows, columns=['pid', 'uid', 'text', 'prediction', 'datetime'])

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

# Optionally, save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('cleaned_logs.csv', index=False)



What regex string should I use to solve such a problem?
I tried going linewise and still wasn't able to capture all the text

In what way can the data be malformed? What you have presented in the question seems to match your patterns at first glance.

Why do you have to use a regular expression? Also, if the file contents are as shown in the question then, by definition, it's not a TSV

I don't think your data constitutes a valid TSV. It seems that some "records" are split over more than one line.
It also appears that a record is delimited by a PID (left) and a date/time pair (right).
Therefore, if you join 2 adjacent tokens and are able to form a valid date/time object then you have probably identified the end of record.
Assuming there's no ambiguity in the text part then you could do this:
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

with open("foo.tsv") as fd:
    tokens = fd.read().split()
    data = defaultdict(list)
    k = 0
    for i in range(3, len(tokens)):
        try:
            dt = pd.to_datetime(" ".join(tokens[i-1:i+1]), format=FMT)
            data["pid"].append(tokens[k])
            data["uid"].append(tokens[k + 1])
            data["text"].append(" ".join(tokens[k + 2 : i - 2]))
            data["prediction"].append(tokens[i - 2])
            data["datetime"].append(dt)
            k = i + 1
        except ValueError:
            pass

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    print(df)

Output:
              pid             uid                                               text prediction            datetime
0  ps8trw17rlo16s  dh7r1wjixjse72  Theoretical movements expensive. In rural area...   positive 2020-06-01 00:00:00
1  psw4o545h8gc2h  dhykkf6486p9ra  Ave SW components on the East in 1498, and soo...   positive 2020-06-01 00:07:00
2  pscnx5eqtjocca  dhn4dhhp3wm5lt  Kinds are larger, possibly over two million. T...   positive 2020-06-01 00:14:00

